# Tensorflow-Deeplearning - Correlation between input and output

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, correlation, tensor

I'm experimenting with tensorflow for speech recognition.

I have inputs as waveforms and words as output.

The waveform would look like this

```
[0,0,0,-2,3,-4,-1,7,0,0,0...0,0,0,20,-11,4,0,0,1,...]
```

The words would be an array of numbers while each number represents a word:

```
[12,4,2,3]
```

After training I also want to find out the correlation between input and output for each output label.

For example I want to know which input neurons | samples are responsible for the first label (here 12).

```
[0,0.01,0.10,0.99,0.77,0.89,0.99,0.79,0.22,0.11,0...0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...]
```

The original values of the input would be replaced with the correlation while 0 means no correlation and 1 means total correlation.

The goal is to get the position when a word starts.

Is there a function in tensorflow to get this correlation?

Comment: I don't think there's a function that will do that for you out of the box. It would probably depend on what model you're using and how you can extract "meaning" from that (as abstract as that sounds)

Comment: I'm thinking of some method to walk through the way the information took from the input neurons to the output neurons and see how "strong" each neuron was involved for each output value. I don't even know how to call this. Is there already a name for that?

Comment: 1) This is a very abstract discussion and I don't think anyone can give you any advice without seeing what you're doing, and 2) this depends entirely on your network structure. If you're doing some sort of RNN then you might want to look into attention, if you're doing some form of convolutional temporal model you might want to look into deconv layers or something

Comment: Maybe this image helps to understand,what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/lKUliXK

Comment: You might be able to use [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients)(i.e. `tf.gradients(output,input)`). It's not going to give you a value between 0 and 1, but the magnitude of the gradient at a specific location give you information about which parts of the input vector influence the output the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

I have a sequence of data (X) that I want to translate into another sequence of data (Y) as well as report what part of (X) contributed to (Y).

## Answer

This is a well known problem and Tensorflow.org actually has a fantastic example [neural machine translation with attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/nmt_with_attention)

The example code show how to translate X (Spanish) into Y (English) and report what part of X contributes to the decision of each part of Y (attention)

The exact same principle and code can be used to translate X (wave data) into Y (words) and report what part of the wave data contributes to each word via the attention readout.

The attention layer in the example is called **attention_layer**.